# How do I get the sha for the parent commits while in a conflicted merge state?

Tags: git

The problem I'm trying to solve is I want to get a diff of the files rather than the file with the conflict markers. This is for a script so plumbing commands would be best. I assume the best way would be to find out the sha for the parents and then use them to get the diff but if there's a more direct way then let me know.

Comment: The merge has not happened yet so you're still on the HEAD commit on the source of the merge.  The other items are stored in `.git/MERGE_HEAD` as I recall.  But, there are also syntactic tricks to extract conflicted files via the index: `:0:README`, etc.  See [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conflicting file data is stored in the index, and can be retrieved for a file with the `git-ls-files` command.  Each entry in the index has a "stage" value, between 0-3 that indicates the type of entry:

- 0: a normal entry in the index, a file that is staged
- 1: the common ancestor file in a conflict
- 2: the "ours" side in a conflict; the file that exists in HEAD
- 3: the "theirs" side in a conflict; the file that exists in the branch you are merging in

When a conflict occurs, stage 0 entries for a file are removed and stages 1, 2 and 3 are written as appropriate to indicate that the file is in conflict.  When you have resolved a conflict and `git add` the appropriate resolution, the stage 0 entry is added and the high stage entries are removed.

For example, if I attempt to merge a branch that creates a conflict on `a.txt`:

```
% git merge br
Auto-merging a.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Then you can view the hashes of the files involved in the `a.txt` and their stages for conflict with `git-ls-files`:

```
% git ls-files --stage
100644 6041e76b484cbe25004efdf4e5faf3396d6f95a6 1       a.txt
100644 0b6a7cf8dc44738a17d322c315ded9265f38a3fa 2       a.txt
100644 67244df04c82140ad8e763a52daa670878b9d574 3       a.txt
```

If you want a simple way to get the hash for a single entry, you can use [git revision syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to refer to an item at a stage.  To get the hash for the conflicting file in "their" branch (being merged in):

```
% git rev-parse :3:a.txt
67244df04c82140ad8e763a52daa670878b9d574
```

Once I have merged the file manually, I can stage the resolution with `git add`:

```
% echo "resolved!" > a.txt
% git add a.txt
```

And only the stage 0 entry will remain:

```
% git ls-files --stage a.txt
100644 8a1c1b8cc46d9c722630b3bf561ecde155554831 0       a.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! diff on 1 to 3 it is.